# Redirect Specific URL if Loaded in UIWebview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to detect if a specific url is being loaded in a uiwebview and if so redirect the webview to a different url. So far I've got the following code which should seem to work for me but no luck so far, anyone know what I'm doing wrong:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    if(request.URL == [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://cheese.com/"])
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/"];
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

    } else {

    }

    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: whats the error you are facing?

Comment: The URL is not recognized and therefore neither redirected

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310258/reliable-way-to-compare-two-nsurl-or-one-nsurl-and-an-nsstring

Comment: @user1419810 : URL not recognized means? What is the error?

Comment: There is no actual error to speak of - nothing in the logs etc, it just doesnt recognise the url being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if([request.URL.relativeString isEqualToString:@"https://cheese.com/"]) {

}
```