# How to check if the request address and response address are the same

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

A user uses an internet connection where he is redirected to an internet providers login page.

Running a request before he has logged in will give you html data from the provider and data from the address that you originally requested data from.

Is there a way to check if the data address that you request data from is the same address that you get the response from?

i.e.

Is there a way to get the response URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLResponse` both have a `URL` property, but comparing them using `-isEqual:` [may not give you the desired result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801580/how-to-compare-two-nsurls-that-are-practically-equivalent-but-have-cosmetic-stri). Here's a category on `NSURL` that will help:

```
@interface NSURL (Equivalence)
- (BOOL)isEquivalent:(NSURL *)aURL;
@end

@implementation NSURL (Equivalence)
- (BOOL)isEquivalent:(NSURL *)aURL
{
    if ([self isEqual:aURL]) return YES;
    if ([[self scheme] caseInsensitiveCompare:[aURL scheme]] != NSOrderedSame) return NO;
    if ([[self host] caseInsensitiveCompare:[aURL host]] != NSOrderedSame) return NO;
    if ([[self path] compare:[aURL path]] != NSOrderedSame) return NO;
    if ([[self port] compare:[aURL port]] != NSOrderedSame) return NO;
    if ([[self query] compare:[aURL query]] != NSOrderedSame) return NO;
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Import that category, and you could do something like the following with AFNetworking:

```
[self getPath:@"somePath" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if ([operation.request.URL isEquivalent:operation.response.URL]) {
        // they match
    } else {
        // there was a redirect
    }
} failure:nil];
```

EDIT: I've long since incorporated `NSURL+Equivalence` into my standard toolbox, but credit belongs to [danh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh) and [this excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332091/840428).